# Calculate collision point of rigid body in BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, coordinates, collision

I have a sphere (active rigid body) that bounces on a plane (passive rigid body) and afterwards hits another plane (passive rigid body).
I would like to get its coordinates when it hits the second plane via the python api.

Right now, I calculate the collision point by using the velocity vector between frames and using some interpolation but it seems to be not 100% accurate. Unfortunately, I can't find any simple examples on how to check for collisions. All I found out is that I have to use the game engine for this task. Could someone give a simple example of how to do this in python?